# Sending song metadata to a v2.6 Shoutcast server in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, curl, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to send “Now Playing” metadata to a ShoutCast v2 server.
The following works in a Windows batch file using CURL v7.47:

```
CURL "http://<server_username>:<server_password>@<server_IP>:8000/admin.cgi?<stream_password>&mode=updinfo&song=XXXXXXX - XXXXXXX"
```

....although for some reason I get errors if I use CURL v7.83.

Anyway, that’s not my main issue. I am migrating the Windows batch file to PowerShell and would like to use the built-in PowerShell command such as Invoke-WebRequest.

In PowerShell, if I use:

```
$url = "http://${SC_server_username}:${SC_server_password}@${SC_ip_address}:${SC_port}/admin.cgi?${SC_stream_password}&mode=updinfo&song=${song}"

& ./curl.exe $url1 2> $null
```

Then it works. But when I use:

```
$url = "http://${SC_server_username}:${SC_server_password}@${SC_ip_address}:${SC_port}/admin.cgi?${SC_stream_password}&mode=updinfo&song=${song}"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url
```

I get the error:

```
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using `-Credential` (and `-AllowUnencryptedAuthentication`) instead of putting the credentials in the URL?

Comment: Is that the full [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) error message? If not, does the full error message reveal something similar to the errors you get with `curl` v7.83?